# How do I tell if my video card can support 4K resolutions?

Tags: display, graphics-card

I have dual Radeon HD 6850's in a CrossFire configuration.  Both cards have a single DisplayPort 1.2 port.  According to the AMD specs on the 6800 series, the cards will support ">2560x2048" when using DisplayPort, but doesn't specifically state that it will support the 3840 x 2160 used by the Dell P2815Q I'm looking at.

Is there any way to tell for sure whether or not I'll be able to run at the 4K resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your graphics cards just won't work.  For a 4K display to run at 60Hz, you need either two HDMI or two DisplayPort connectors, and from what I've read Crossfire isn't working well in 4K.  Even if you were able to get an updated driver for your card that would allow you to run at 4K resolutions, you'd be limited to 30Hz because of bandwidth limitations in both HDMI and DisplayPort cables.  AMD's first attempt at 4K support was the HD7900 series, with the fully supported options being 280x and 290x.

See [this article](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/pq321q-4k-gaming,3620.html) for more info on 4K.

Answer (score 2):

Technically DP 1.2 has enough bandwidth to support 4K without any issues. But it seems like the max supported resolution for HD 6850 is 2560x1600 per display from [AMD's own specs](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/amd-radeon-hd-6000/hd-6850/pages/amd-radeon-hd-6850-overview.aspx#2) on the card.

```
DisplayPort 1.2
Max resolution: 2560x1600 per display
Multi-Stream Transport
21.6 Gbps bandwidth
High bit-rate audio
```